Springboot Angular chat implementation
Can any one help in implementing an one to one chat application in Angular and spring boot as a backend with websocket. Basically i want to implement a chat application in my website where all users can communicate with single admin.
I have tried to implement chat, but it works globally, means if one user sent a message, that message can be seen by all logged in users. I need private chat between user and admin
